# ffmpeg slideshow video from images creating empty mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` to create an `.mp4` from a set of `.JPG` files. This is the `ffmpeg` line I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i image-%03d.JPG output.mp4
```

which returns:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 04ee8ca0] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, image2, from 'image-%03d.JPG':
  Duration: 00:01:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4608x3072, 0.20 tbr, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
No pixel format specified, yuvj422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] frame MB size (288x192) > level limit (36864)
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] DPB size (4 frames, 221184 mbs) > level limit (3 frames, 184320 mbs)
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] profile High 4:2:2, level 5.2, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj422p(pc), 4608x3072, q=-1--1, 0.20 fps, 16384 tbn, 0.20 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   13 fps=0.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=   18249kB time=00:00:55.00 bitrate=2718.2kbits/s
video:18249kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.005057%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] frame I:1     Avg QP:13.94  size:1564617
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] frame P:12    Avg QP:13.68  size:1426766
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] mb I  I16..4:  2.6% 79.2% 18.2%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] mb P  I16..4:  2.2% 82.9% 14.6%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] 8x8 transform intra:82.9% inter:79.9%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 95.0% 80.5% 67.2% inter: 33.6% 27.6% 11.4%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 16%  9%  5% 69%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 20% 24%  6%  8%  6%  8%  6% 10%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 22% 10%  8% 11%  8% 11%  6%  9%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 20% 20%  7%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.3% UV:8.3%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] ref P L0: 64.6%  9.0% 11.8%  5.8%  8.8%
[libx264 @ 04ef4a40] kb/s:2299.79
```

and a `output.mp4`. When I run this file, it ends immediately without showing any images. I don't see any errors or problems in the code, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to increase the video framerate or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some players have troubles with low framerates. Also, the pixel format may not be supported by the player.

Use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i image-%03d.JPG -r 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```